# How to get the fatest way of getting the maximum values element-wised of "n" matrices in Python/Numpy?

Tags: python, performance, matrix, numpy, max

I had like to know the best fatest/optimized way of getting the maximum values element-wised of "n" matrices in Python/Numpy.

For example:

```
import numpy as np
matrices=[np.random.random((5,5)) for i in range(10)]
# the function np.maximum from numpy only works for two matrices.
max_matrix=np.maximum(matrices[0],matrices[1])
max_matrix=np.maximum(*matrices) # <- error
```

How would you overcome this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `reduce`:

```
reduce(np.maximum, matrices)
```

From the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#reduce):

> `reduce`(*function*, *iterable*[, *initializer*])
>
> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of iterable,
>   from left to right, so as to reduce the iterable to a single value.
>   For example, `reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])` calculates
>   `((((1+2)+3)+4)+5)`. The left argument, `x`, is the accumulated value and
>   the right argument, `y`, is the update value from the iterable. If the
>   optional initializer is present, it is placed before the items of the
>   iterable in the calculation, and serves as a default when the iterable
>   is empty. If initializer is not given and iterable contains only one
>   item, the first item is returned.

Comment: +1 That's pretty awesome and is a bit faster than either Justin or my answers, especially for large matrices.

Comment: I find it strange that np.maximum.reduce(matrices) is slower than this. My bet is that numpy converts matrices using np.array first.

Answer (score 3):

```
import numpy as np
matrices=[np.random.random((5,5)) for i in range(10)]
np.max(np.hstack(matrices))
```

Will give you the maximum value from all of the n matrices. This basically merges all of the matrices in `matrices` into a single array using `np.hstack` and then takes the max of that new array. This assumes that all of your matrices have the same number of rows. You can also use `np.vstack` or `np.concatenate` to achieve a similar effect.

**Edit** I re-read your question and you might actually want something more like:

```
np.max(np.dstack(matrices),axis=2)
```

This will stack all of your matrices along a third axis and then give you the max along that direction, returning a 5x5 matrix for your case.

**Edit #2** Here are some timings:

```
In [33]: matrices = [np.random.random((5,5)) for i in range(10)]

In [34]: %timeit np.dstack(matrices).max(2)
10000 loops, best of 3: 92.6 us per loop

In [35]: %timeit np.array(matrices).max(axis=0)
10000 loops, best of 3: 90.9 us per loop

In [36]: %timeit reduce(np.maximum, matrices)
10000 loops, best of 3: 25.8 us per loop
```

and for some larger arrays:

```
In [37]: matrices = [np.random.random((200,200)) for i in range(100)]

In [38]: %timeit np.dstack(matrices).max(2)
10 loops, best of 3: 111 ms per loop

In [39]: %timeit np.array(matrices).max(axis=0)
1 loops, best of 3: 697 ms per loop

In [40]: %timeit reduce(np.maximum, matrices)
100 loops, best of 3: 12.7 ms per loop
```

Steven wins!

Comment: The OP wants an output matrix where each element is the max of all of the elements located at that same position in the input matrices.

Comment: Fixed it before I saw your comment